# Complex number algebra, help

Tags: complex-numbers

I have $ \lambda^{2} = \pm i \frac{\omega}{\nu} $

when I try and solve for lambda i dont get the same answer as my text book.

the book $ \lambda =\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{\nu}}$

how do they get this?

Comment: What do you get?

Comment: Hint:$$-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The square roots of $i$ are $\pm (i+1)/\sqrt 2$ and the square roots of $-i$ are $\pm (i-1)/\sqrt 2.$ Let $x^2=\omega /\nu$. If $\lambda^2=i \omega/\nu$ then $\lambda=\pm x(1+i)/\sqrt 2,$ or if $\lambda^2=-i\omega/\nu$ then $\lambda=\pm x(1-i)/\sqrt 2.$